# Android tooltip up word

Tags: android, vector, tooltip

in my android application tooltip is there ,created by using vector path but it is downward direction I want opposite direction ie upward which portion I need to change in my code please help me. 
this is my code

```
[![< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

< vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="44dp"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:viewportHeight="182"
    android:viewportWidth="196">
    < path
        android:fillColor="#109af1"

        android:pathData="M0 26.9917C0 12.0846 12.09433 0  26.99583 0L169.0042 0C183.9136 0 196 12.09104 196 26.9917L196 100.0083C196 114.9154 183.9057 127 169.0042 127L124 127L98.5 162L73 127L26.99583 127C12.08644 127 0 114.909 0 100.0083L0 26.9917" />
< /vector>][1]][1]
```

i done this style
[image]

i want this style

[image]

Comment: designer can help you for this vector image

Comment: you need to change the Path Data, try Doing Experiment with it. If you don't have time ask  Designer

Comment: i tried ,but  failed

Comment: i dont have any desgners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="180"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="80%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="44dp"
                android:height="30dp"
                android:viewportHeight="182"
                android:viewportWidth="196">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="#109af1"
                    android:pathData="M0 26.9917C0 12.0846 12.09433 0  26.99583 0L169.0042 0C183.9136 0 196 12.09104 196 26.9917L196 100.0083C196 114.9154 183.9057 127 169.0042 127L124 127L98.5 162L73 127L26.99583 127C12.08644 127 0 114.909 0 100.0083L0 26.9917" />
            </vector>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]